# 'ToArray' is not a member of 'String'

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I found a code example online that purports to count the number of pages in a PDF file.  However, I'm getting the error 'ToArray is not a member of 'String' on the following line:

```
Dim pdfMagicNumber() As Char = "0000".ToArray
```

I'm running VS 2010 on a Framework 2.0 project, on a machine running Windows 7 and IIS 7.  I found one article that talked about IIS configuration as the culprit for this error, but my settings seem to be consistent with what they recommended.

Any ideas on this error?

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: I believe in the .NET 2.0 framework `.ToArray()` is not a member of `string`. Try `ToCharArray()`. If I am correct the `.ToArray()` method is an `Enumerable` extension that just so happens to work on strings under the premise of a `IEnumerable<char>` that was introduced with LINQ in 3.5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) is an extension method introduced in .NET 3.5 on `IEnumerable<T>`. It works in .NET 3.5+ when called on `string`, as `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

However, [`string.ToCharArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx) is available in *all* versions of .NET, and even when you're using .NET 3.5+, it will be more efficient than `ToArray`.

In other words, you want:

```
Dim pdfMagicNumber() As Char = "0000".ToCharArray
```

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks so much Jon, for the solution and detailed answer.  Works great now!

Comment: ToArray also requires the `System.Linq` namespace imported under `Project Properties > References > Imported namespaces`. Took me a while to figure that out. Shouldn't be an issue unless you've updated the target framework in your project.